# Control transform: scaleX & transform: scaleY independently with javascript on the same object using sliders

Tags: javascript, css, scale, translate

The following code allows them to be controlled individually, my issue is if you adjust one, then adjust the other, the value for the first you adjusted is lost (removed) instead of added (appended?) to the inline css.

```js
function scaleXfont(e) {
  var scaleamount = document.getElementById("scaleXslider").value;
  document.getElementById("transscale").style.transform = "scaleX(" + scaleamount + ")";
  currentcss();
}

function scaleYfont(e) {
  var scaleamount = document.getElementById("scaleYslider").value;
  document.getElementById("transscale").style.transform = "scaleY(" + scaleamount + ")";
  currentcss();
}

function currentcss() {
document.getElementById("currentcss").innerText = document.getElementById("transscale").style.cssText;
}
```

```html
<div class="singlecontrol">
<span style="vertical-align: middle;">ScaleX</span>
<input style="vertical-align: middle;" id="scaleXslider" oninput="scaleXfont(event)" type="range" value="0.0" min="-10" max="10" step="0.01" autocomplete="off" />
</div>

<div class="singlecontrol"
><span style="vertical-align: middle;">ScaleY</span>
<input style="vertical-align: middle;" id="scaleYslider" oninput="scaleYfont(event)" type="range" value="0.0" min="-10" max="10" step="0.01" autocomplete="off" /></div>

<div id="cssinuse">
Current CSS = <br />
<span id="currentcss"></span>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div style="display:inline-block; width:100%; text-align:center;">
<div id="transscale">Stretch/Flip Me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi ! Yes, you have to remember and put the 2 values, separated with a space each time.

Comment: @Philippe How would I do that? Do I have to get the current value (if set) for the other then append?

Comment: Yes you should :)

Comment: Could you (or anyone) please give a based on my code example answer, I seem to have the right theory on what I need to do but not able (tried a few things now) to actually get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now solved by grabbing both slider values and applying them at the same time using

`var scaleXamount = document.getElementById("scaleXslider").value;`

`var scaleYamount = document.getElementById("scaleYslider").value;`

`style.transform = "scale(" + scaleXamount + ", " + scaleYamount + ")";`

It was the comment

> transform will need to have both scales set in it all the time.

that made me think this way so thank you.

Working code..

```js
function scalefont(e) {
  var scaleXamount = document.getElementById("scaleXslider").value;
  var scaleYamount = document.getElementById("scaleYslider").value;
  document.getElementById("transscale").style.transform = "scale(" + scaleXamount + ", " + scaleYamount + ")";
  currentcss();
}

function currentcss() {
document.getElementById("currentcss").innerText = document.getElementById("transscale").style.cssText;
}
```

```html
<div class="singlecontrol">
<span style="vertical-align: middle;">ScaleX</span>
<input style="vertical-align: middle;" id="scaleXslider" oninput="scalefont(event)" type="range" value="1.0" min="-10" max="10" step="0.001" autocomplete="off" />
</div>

<div class="singlecontrol"
><span style="vertical-align: middle;">ScaleY</span>
<input style="vertical-align: middle;" id="scaleYslider" oninput="scalefont(event)" type="range" value="1.0" min="-10" max="10" step="0.001" autocomplete="off" /></div>

<div id="cssinuse">
Current CSS = <br />
<span id="currentcss"></span>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div style="display:inline-block; width:100%; text-align:center;">
<div id="transscale">Stretch/Flip Me</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

transform will need to have both scales set in it all the time.

To avoid having to get the current values each time and then do string comparisons/replacements this snippet gets the JS to set a couple of CSS variables --x and --y with the style in the element being of this form:

```
style="transform: scaleX(var(--x)) scaleY(var(--y));"
```

```js
function scaleXfont(e) {
  var scaleamount = document.getElementById("scaleXslider").value;
  document.getElementById("transscale").style.setProperty('--x', scaleamount);
  currentcss();
}

function scaleYfont(e) {
  var scaleamount = document.getElementById("scaleYslider").value;
  document.getElementById("transscale").style.setProperty('--y', scaleamount);
  currentcss();
}

function currentcss() {
  document.getElementById("currentcss").innerText = document.getElementById("transscale").style.cssText;
}
```

```html
<div class="singlecontrol">
  <span style="vertical-align: middle;">ScaleX</span>
  <input style="vertical-align: middle;" id="scaleXslider" oninput="scaleXfont(event)" type="range" value="0.0" min="-10" max="10" step="0.01" autocomplete="off" />
</div>

<div class="singlecontrol"><span style="vertical-align: middle;">ScaleY</span>
  <input style="vertical-align: middle;" id="scaleYslider" oninput="scaleYfont(event)" type="range" value="0.0" min="-10" max="10" step="0.01" autocomplete="off" /></div>

<div id="cssinuse">
  Current CSS = <br />
  <span id="currentcss"></span>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div style="display:inline-block; width:100%; text-align:center;">
  <div id="transscale" style="transform: scaleX(var(--x)) scaleY(var(--y)); --x: 1; --y: 1;">Stretch/Flip Me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, are you aware this code doesn't function as intended because no transform scale is applied to the "Stretch/Flip Me" div (at least this is the case for me in Firefox)

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for checking - somehow a missing colon and the inital conditions got missed off when I put the code into the snippet from my system. Should be OK now - could you check? I've tested on Edge/Windows10.

Comment: Having said that, yes the values are changed and to the values picked up from the slider but these need adjusting.

Comment: Yes seems to now change them from sliders as needed, so thank you for that. the CSS output text seems a little odd though with the vars showing

Comment: I didn't change the way the CSS text was output - I thtink you'd have to look at that to remove the vars.

Comment: Sorry i mean the actual css, now getting `transform: scaleX(var(--x)) scaleY(var(--y)); --x: 1.61; --y: 1;` was expecting `transform: scale(1.61,1); /* Equal to scaleX(0.61) scaleY(1) */`

Comment: Now solved by grabbing both slider values and applying them at the same time using `style.transform = "scale(" + scaleXamount + ", " + scaleYamount + ")";`  it was the comment `transform will need to have both scales set in it all the time.` that made me think this way so thank you.